# Angular 5 : API not calling after bad request on ngModelChange

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have to display if the city enterd by the user in a text box is available or not. For that on ngModelChange of the textbox, I am calling a function onCityChange(). In that function, I am emitting user entered data on rxjs Subject. I have subscribed to that Subject in ngOnInit() method. I also have rxjs switchMap() operator in which I am calling the weather search API (in which I will get city name also) through a service.

Now when I enter a correct city name, the API is firing with that city name with HTTP 200 status. After that I am also able to enter another city name and the API is fired with that city name. When a wrong city name is entered, the API is fired with HTTP 404 status as expected. But after that when I enter a correct city name, no API is fired. That is once the API is fired with non success status, it is not firing again with any city name re-entered. What could be wrong?

Here are the code snippets

weather-search.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City" [(ngModel)]="city" (ngModelChange)="onCityChange();">
City found: <b>{{data.name}}</b>
```

weather-search.component.ts

```
    private city: string = '';
    private data: any = {};
    private searchStream = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) { }

    onCityChange(){
        if(this.city)
          this.searchStream.next(this.city);
        else
          this.data = {};
      }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.searchStream
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((input: string) => this.weatherService.searchWeatherData(input))
        .subscribe(
          (data) => this.data = data,
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.data = {};
          })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behaviour. When a subscriber receives an error notification it unsubscribes and thus disposes the chain which is exactly what happens in your case.

You know that `this.weatherService.searchWeatherData(input)` might end with an error so instead of just passing it further you can catch it and replace it with whatever you want. Looks like an empty response is enough:

```
...
.switchMap((input: string) => this.weatherService.searchWeatherData(input)
  .catch(error => Observable.empty())
)
...
```

This will catch each error notification and replace it with `Observable.empty()` before it's merge into the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of `fromEvent` static method of `Observable` as follows:

```
@ViewChild('city') city: ElementRef;



 ngOnInit() {
             Observable.fromEvent(this.city.nativeElement, 'input')
            .debounceTime(500)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap((input: string) => this.weatherService.searchWeatherData(input))
            .subscribe(
              (data) => this.data = data,
              (err) => {
                console.error(err);
                this.data = {};
              })
          }
```